# File uploads to server. Do I need to check for viruses?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2012

A proposed website will allow people to register for jobs and upload their CV's as they register. The CV is then picked up off the server by a third party using automatic ftp transfer and stored on their servers. An end user, then downloads said file to open on their PC.

The thrid party has said that they do not check for viruses in the files and that they see it as the responsiblity of the people either side of the file transfer.

If I take the same approach, and say its up to the end users to scan the files as they upload/download them, is there any risk to the server hosting the site in terms of infection?

The file extension is likely to be limited to .pdf, .txt .doc etc.

I'd like to avoid the headache of finding an anti-virus product that I can script to scan the file in real time if possible.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94356/can-malicious-code-trigger-without-the-user-executing-or-opening-the-file)

Comment: If you accept arbitrary files from your users and then allow another users to download those same files - sure you should ensure they are not dangerous.

Comment: But the third party which ultimately hosts the files clearly doesn't take that point of view.

Answer (score 1):

**Warn the End-User**

There's no way you can make sure who downloads those files is safe, not even by scanning all those files with some AV.

If you could add an AV to that server (doesn't WinServer2012 come with the integrated Windows Defender?) that would obviously be better.

However, while it might be nice and give the user a professional feeling and added *illusion* of security, it is the end-users responsibility to make sure he's protected. Even the most trusted websites might feature some adds that were hijacked and thus infect its visitors.

Make it *very clear* to the user, before he starts any download, that these files were provided by a third-party that is not under your control.

I'd say that's enough.

**Additional steps**

You could restrict the file type to be PDF, TXT files aren't very professional, and all major Office applications (free included) feature a way to export to PDF (so no DOC files are needed). That reduces the attack surface and you could even manage to implement your own way of scanning those PDF files. There should be C# libraries that are able to read those PDF files and extract any fishy content for validation, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305505/how-do-i-extract-attachments-from-a-pdf-file) is a nice example.

Comment: Verifying file types has its own set of issues. Now your application code is opening user submitted files....it's possible for someone to sneak an exploit into that file.

Comment: That's right @mason, although he is already "opening" those files when he downloads them from the client computer to his website. There are many ways such a website might be exploited, not only at the file content level. He's bound to at least partially validate the data his clients send him, isn't he?

Comment: Copying bytes around isn't  the same as opening them with a library and actually parsing the contents. Let's say you receive a file with a .pdf extension, so you try to use iTextSharp to open the file to verify it's a valid PDF. Now any security bugs in iTextSharp can be taken advantage of by an attacker. And it doesn't require all that much knowledge by an attacker to exploit. It's a popular library and it's often not hard to make an educated guess what technology stack a website uses.

Comment: Absolutely, but, while harder to do, even a simple file upload can be exploited if no precautions are taken. Scanning those files wasn't meant as a quick solution to a much bigger issue anyway. It is however a possible compromise in case no AV can be used, but the user still wants some sort of additional validation. This obviously comes with its own downsides.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The download of the files would be via a separate CRM app provided by the third party who ultimately hosts the file, so I cannot control any warnings etc.. As Im' guessing not all users with a CV may be able to export to PDF they may not find that approach acceptible. I agree that opening the file may be a risk to the server. I suppose the solution is simialr to that suggestion initially - warn the user not to upload infected files, and verbally tell the CRM user (my client) they need to check the files for viruses.