# Read Attached XML from PDF

Tags: r, xml, pdf

I have the same problem [as posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305505/how-do-i-extract-attachments-from-a-pdf-file): a big number pdf documents with xml files attached to them. I would like to extract and read them. However, I would like to use R. Is that possible?

I looked at the docs from `pdftools` and it seems not supported.

Comment: Just found `pdftools::pdf_attachments`. It's just that simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the simplest one program line library to **PDFdetach** files is **xpdf or Poppler Utilities**

> pdfdetach: extracts attached files from PDF files

For R they are **included as PDFtools** https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pdftools/versions/3.3.2/topics/pdftools

Manual is at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftools/pdftools.pdf but does not give any simple example of use for extract a files content.

Thus for any OS ensure they are included

You can run direct the binaries as xpdf version for 32bit users or poppler version for 64bit users

R documentation does not cover all the options available in the standalone binaries which include `-list`, `-save` and `-saveall` along with others.